# Can you describe sheets and or visuals using the AWS Quicksight API?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

After writing some code to extract information about Dashboards, Analyses, Datasets and Datasources from AWS Quicksight using the QuickSight API (Allowing for full text search on objects and queries in use, and allowing for change-detection), I noticed that I would like to have information on sheet contents and visuals as well.

However, it seems the cli does not allow retreiving those details.

Is this correct? Am I missing something?

I also would love to be able to create visuals using the API, is this possible?

Comment: The Amazon QuickSight API allows you to programmatically manage and interact with your QuickSight resources, including datasets, analyses, dashboards, and visuals. However, the level of control and features available through the API may vary, and it's possible that new features and capabilities have been added since my last update.

Here are some common actions you can perform using the Amazon QuickSight API related to sheets and visuals:

Create a Dashboard: You can use the API to create a new dashboard by specifying its metadata, layout, and the visuals it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End of 2022 Amazon added the AWS CLI commands  [describe-analysis-definition](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/quicksight/describe-analysis-definition.html) and [describe-dashboard-definition](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/quicksight/describe-dashboard-definition.html), next to [DescribeAnalysis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeAnalysis.html) and [describe-dashboard](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/quicksight/describe-dashboard.html), which do exactly what I was looking for.

AWS even has some demos on how to use the output of these queries to create new dashboards from

Answer (score 1):

As far as today, it looks like the answer is no, and it looks like AWS is not taking it in this direction.
The best-practice is to base the visual on generic template and the it can be programmatically described and populated. (Using [describe-template-api](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/quicksight/describe-template.html))

See here more indications and redirections
https://community.amazonquicksight.com/t/api-programmatic-creation-of-sheets-and-visuals/7589